# Conditionally including additional characters using python string formatting

Tags: python

Is it possible using python's string format to conditionally include additional characters along with the string variable only if the variable is not empty?

```
>>> format_string = "{last}, {first}"
>>> name = {'first': 'John', 'last':'Smith'}
>>> format_string.format(**name)
'Smith, John' # great!
>>> name = {'first': 'John', 'last':''}
>>> format_string.format(**name)
', John' # don't want the comma and space here, just 'John'
```

I would like to use the same`format_string` variable to handle any combination of empty or non-empty values for `first` or `last` in the `name` dict.

What's the easiest way to do this in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
>>> format_string = "{last}, {first}"
>>> name = {'first': 'John', 'last':''}
>>> format_string.format(**name).strip(', ')
>>> 'John'
```

Comment: `strip()` would remove it from the first version as well ("SmithJohn"), so I'd still need some kind of `if` structure.

Comment: No it will not. Have you tested it? Strip only removes leading and trailing characters.

Comment: No I didn't test it and yes it does work. I guess I forgot `strip()` only happens at the ends of the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set value for separator based on condition.

```
'{first}{separator}{last}'.format(**{"first":first, "last":last,"separator":(", " if last and first else "")})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run the original dict through a function to 'clean' it, adding commas where appropriate. Or, have a defaultdict.

The following solution, the simplest, does a post-process step to remove any extra commas and spaces:

### source

```
import re

name = {'first': 'John', 'last':''}
format_string = '{last}, {first}'

def fixme(instr):
    return re.sub('^, ', '',
                  re.sub(', $', '',
                         instr))

print fixme(format_string.format(**dict(first='John', last='')))
print
print fixme(format_string.format(**dict(first='', last='Smith')))
```

### output

```
John

Smith
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution scales exponentially.